# Register a global.asax into a SharePoint Site

Tags: development

I'm trying add a `.asax` file into a SharePoint site. 
I've been following [this tutorial](http://spboom.com/sharepoint-development/using-global-asax-with-sharepoint/).

It's quite simple but I'm new to web programming, and I didn't understand where I must insert (and how) the `.dll` file generated by `MyAssembly` project.

And about the global.asax, should I just put it into the `wwwwroot\etc...` directory?

Answer (score 0):

This [post](http://unabo.blogspot.in/2011/04/override-globalasax-in-sharepoint.html) can help you understand better.

But why dont you use httpmodule instead, I would have preferred that. Find this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437483/deploying-global-asax-to-sharepoint-2010-in-an-enterprise-environment-to-enable) question